# Find necessary and sufficent conditions for A to be bijective function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm studying functional analysis. I have a problem in this exercise.

In Hilbert space $(X,<,>)$, $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis, $\{\lambda_n\}$ is a bouded sequence in $\mathbb K$

$A(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k.<x,e_k>.e_k$

$A_n(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k.<x,e_k>.e_k$

I proved A is  linear and continuous and $||A||=\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}|\lambda_k|$.

But the problem is:

> Find necessary and sufficent condtions for A to be a bijective function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: It's easy to guess a formula for $A^{-1}$.  What do you need for that to be continuous?

Answer (score 1):

If $\inf\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_k|>0$ the operator $B: X \rightarrow X$ defined by $B(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k^{-1}\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$ will be linear and bounded. For each $k$ we clearly have $AB(e_k)=e_k$, so by linearity and continuity $AB=I$.

Conversely, suppose $\inf\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_k|=0$. There are two possibilities, either $\lambda_m=0$ for some integer $m$ or $\lambda_k\neq 0$ for all $k$. If the former is true, $A$ isn't injective since $A(e_m)=0$. If the latter is true we can define the operator $B: \text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\} \rightarrow \text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ as before and it we will have $A_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}B=BA_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}=I_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$. If now $A$ was bijective then by the Bounded Inverse Theorem, it would have a bounded inverse, $C:X \rightarrow X$. In particular $C_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ would be bounded inverse for $A_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ so by the uniqueness of an algebraic inverse, we must have $C_{|\text{span}\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}}=B$. But this means that $B$ is bounded which contradicts the fact that $\inf\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_k|=0$. We conclude that  $A$ is *not* bijective.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1). $ if $A(x)=0,$ then taking inner products with each $e_k$ gives $\lambda_k\langle x,e_k\rangle=0.$

$2).\ $ Consider the map $e_k\mapsto \lambda_ke_k.$